# mysql not able to establish remote connection

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench, redhat

Could not able to connect to the remote mysql server using mysql workbench or direct command line.
When trying it resolves different hostname

[image: Mysql workbench error message]

When trying directly through command line

```
mysql --host=10.37.1.92 --port=3306 --user=root --password=password
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'myaapvm.local' (using password: YES)
```

Tried, with password and without password, no luck.

I tried to connect to 10.37.1.92 server but my mysql client try to connect to different server. The only way I can try now is directly login to the machine and do the change in my DB. I have disabled firewall in my mysql DB. Does anyone faced this issue please help.

This server running  with maria DB installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default root is not allowed to access the database by using a remote connection. I recommend that you create a new user that will be used for remote connections. You can do that by using the following SQL commands:

```
    CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
    CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';

    GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
    GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You also need to modify your my.cnf if you didn't do that already.

```
    #Replace xxx with your IP Address 
    bind-address        = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```